# How can I set firebase rule for switch button

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

in the realtime firebase
the child Button's value is 'true'
I want new value has to be only 'false' while it is 'true'
the opposite, it has to be true

how can I code up for firebase rule?

guessing to use data.exists() or 'true' or 'false' as string
but using data.exists() is further reaching to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
".validate": "
  (data.val() === 'true' && newData.val() === 'false') ||
  (data.val() === 'false' && newData.val() === 'true')
"
```

Note that I use string values since you mentioned those in your question, but I usually would store boolean values in an actual boolean node.